# TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

trying to create a height map, but keep getting an TypeError says Image object is not subscriptable.  No idea why.

```
pixels = Image.new('RGB', (1789, 1789), color = 'red')
    for i in range(pixels.size[0]): 
        for j in range(pixels.size[1]):
            if pixels[i,j] != (255, 0, 0):
                pixels[i,j] = (0, 0 ,0)
```

Comment: `Not subscriptable` means `pixels[i,j]` isn't defined. From [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/PixelAccess.html) it looks like you want to write `pixels = Image.new(...).load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single pixel, use `pixels.getpixel((i,j))`.  Note that this is a very slow way to access an Image.  It is often better to use `tobytes` to convert to a byte list, then `frombytes` to convert it back.

Your example is silly, of course.  Every pixel will be (255,0,0).